# AttributeError: 'IntVar' object has no attribute 'config'

Tags: python, tkinter

I would like to enable and disable my checkbutton from tkinter. But im getting these error message. I know that my Problem is in my IntVar() but, How can I configure my checkbutton to enable and disable by using intVar?

> AttributeError: 'IntVar' object has no attribute 'config'

```
def callback():
    if var1.get():
        var2.configure(state = NORMAL)
        var3.configure(state=NORMAL)

var1 = IntVar()
cbtn1 = Checkbutton(master, text= "START", variable=var1, command=call_hands)
cbtn1.pack()

var2 = IntVar()
cbtn1 = Checkbutton(master, text= "One", state=DISABLED, variable=var2)
cbtn1.pack()

var3 = IntVar()
cbtn1 = Checkbutton(master, text= "Two", state=DISABLED, variable=var3)
cbtn1.pack()
```

Comment: You mean ```cbtn1.config()```. Also ```cbtn1``` has the value of only the last ```Checkbutton```

Comment: Ohhh. Sorry, that was my mistake.

Comment: Also, ```IntVar``` only keeps a track of the variable or the values, not the button itself

Comment: Thank you. But how can I implement it so that when I click on the checkbox, the unchecked should be checked and when you click on it again, the checked Checkbutton should be unchecked again. Ive tried something but its not working.

Comment: The code you posted doesn't give the error you say it does.

Comment: Your question and a comment don't seem to align. The question is about how to enable or disable the checkbutton, but in the comment you say  you want to check or uncheck the checkbutton. Please provide a [mcve] and a description that accurately reflects what you need help with.

Answer (score 1):

The error `AttributeError: 'IntVar' object has no attribute 'config'` means that you are trying to call the `config` method on an instance of `IntVar`, and an `IntVar` doesn't have a `config` method.

Variables can't be enabled or disabled, but checkbuttons can. You need to call the `configure` method on an instance of a `Checkbutton`.

Given you have a checkbutton named `cbtn1`, the correct way to change it's state is by calling `cbtn1.configure` to set the `state` attribute (eg: `cbtn1.configure(state=NORMAL)`)